# iText pdf 7 : Digitally sign a pdf

Tags: java, itext7

I am working on implementing a solution for signing a PDF using i text pdf 7. The code is working fine but when the document is opened in adobe it gives "Document has been altered or corrupted since it was signed"

I am not able to figure out on what I am missing

I have attached the code and generated pdf sample as well

```
public void testPoints() {
        try{
            BouncyCastleProvider providerBC = new BouncyCastleProvider();
            Security.addProvider(providerBC);

            InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream("/Users/abhinav/Work/dev/client-wca.p12");

            /* Reading the certificate from a tempory store */
            KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
            ks.load(inStream, "!234Qwer".toCharArray());
            String alias = ks.aliases().nextElement();
            PrivateKey key = (PrivateKey)ks.getKey(alias, "!234Qwer".toCharArray());
            Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate(alias);

            // create PCKS7 for getting attributes
            Certificate[] certificates= Arrays.asList(certificate).toArray(new Certificate[0]);

            //CREATE an empty signature placeholder
            PreSignatureContainerToSign preSignatureContainerToSign = emptySignature("/Users/abhinav/Work/dev/dummy.pdf", "/Users/abhinav/Work/dev/SL_SIGNED.pdf",
                    "sig", certificates, key);

//            byte[] signature = sign(preSignatureContainerToSign.hash, key);

            //Sign the PDF with original has
            createSignature("/Users/abhinav/Work/dev/SL_SIGNED.pdf", "/Users/abhinav/Work/dev/SL_SIGNED_f.pdf",
                    "sig", preSignatureContainerToSign.hash, certificates, key, preSignatureContainerToSign);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

private PreSignatureContainerToSign emptySignature(String src, String dest, String fieldname, Certificate[] chain, PrivateKey key)
            throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
        PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest), new StampingProperties());
        PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = signer.getSignatureAppearance();
        appearance.setPageRect(new Rectangle(100, 400, 200, 100));
        appearance.setPageNumber(1);
        appearance.setCertificate(chain[0]);
//        appearance.setReason("For test");
//        appearance.setLocation("HKSAR");
        signer.setFieldName(fieldname);

        /*
         * ExternalBlankSignatureContainer constructor will create the PdfDictionary for
         * the signature information and will insert the /Filter and /SubFilter values
         * into this dictionary. It will leave just a blank placeholder for the
         * signature that is to be inserted later.
         */
        PreSignatureContainerToSign external = new PreSignatureContainerToSign(PdfName.Adobe_PPKLite,
                PdfName.Adbe_pkcs7_detached);
        external.setCertificates(chain);
        external.setKey(key);

        // Sign the document using an external container.
        // 8192 is the size of the empty signature placeholder.
        signer.signExternalContainer(external, 8192);
        return external;
    }

    private void createSignature(String src, String dest, String fieldName, byte[] sig, Certificate[] chain,
                                 PrivateKey key, PreSignatureContainerToSign preSignatureContainerToSign)
            throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
        try (FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dest)) {
            PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(reader, os, new StampingProperties().useAppendMode());

            PreSignatureContainer external = new PreSignatureContainer(PdfName.Adobe_PPKLite,
                    PdfName.Adbe_pkcs7_detached, true, sig,
                    preSignatureContainerToSign.hash);
            external.setCertificates(chain);
            external.setKey(key);
            // Signs a PDF where space was already reserved. The field must cover the whole
            // document.
            PdfSigner.signDeferred(signer.getDocument(), fieldName, os, external);
        }
    }

    public class PreSignatureContainer implements IExternalSignatureContainer {
        private PdfDictionary sigDic;
        private PrivateKey key;
        private Certificate[] certificates;
        private byte hash[];
        private byte[] signature;
        private byte[] original;
        public void setCertificates(Certificate[] certificates) {
            this.certificates = certificates;
        }

        public void setKey(PrivateKey key) {
            this.key = key;
        }

        public PreSignatureContainer(PdfName filter, PdfName subFilter, boolean flag, byte[] signature,  byte[] original) {
            sigDic = new PdfDictionary();
            sigDic.put(PdfName.Filter, filter);
            sigDic.put(PdfName.SubFilter, subFilter);
            this.signature = signature;
            this.original = original;
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] sign(InputStream data) throws GeneralSecurityException {
            BouncyCastleDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();

            try {
                var sgn = new PdfPKCS7(null, this.certificates,
                        DigestAlgorithms.SHA256, null, digest, false);
                sgn.setExternalDigest(signature,null, "RSA");
                return sgn.getEncodedPKCS7(original, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS,
                        null, null, null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new GeneralSecurityException("PreSignatureContainer signing exception", e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void modifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary signDic) {
            signDic.putAll(sigDic);
        }

        public byte[] getHash() {
            return hash;
        }
    }

    public class PreSignatureContainerToSign implements IExternalSignatureContainer {
        private PdfDictionary sigDic;
        private PrivateKey key;
        private Certificate[] certificates;
        private byte hash[];
        private byte original[];

        public void setCertificates(Certificate[] certificates) {
            this.certificates = certificates;
        }

        public void setKey(PrivateKey key) {
            this.key = key;
        }

        public PreSignatureContainerToSign(PdfName filter, PdfName subFilter) {
            sigDic = new PdfDictionary();
            sigDic.put(PdfName.Filter, filter);
            sigDic.put(PdfName.SubFilter, subFilter);
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] sign(InputStream data) throws GeneralSecurityException {
            String hashAlgorithm = "SHA256";

            BouncyCastleDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
            try {
                var sgn = new PdfPKCS7(null, this.certificates, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256, null,
                        new BouncyCastleDigest(), false);
                original = DigestAlgorithms.digest(data, digest.getMessageDigest(hashAlgorithm));
                // get attributes
                byte [] docsBytes = sgn.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(original,
                        PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS,
                        null, null);

                this.hash = DigestAlgorithms.digest(new ByteArrayInputStream(docsBytes), digest.getMessageDigest(hashAlgorithm));
                return  new byte[0];
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new GeneralSecurityException("PreSignatureContainer signing exception", e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void modifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary pdfDictionary) {
            pdfDictionary.putAll(sigDic);
        }

    }
```

**EDIT**

Updating the code as it being used to generate the file

```
public void testPoints() {
        try{
            BouncyCastleProvider providerBC = new BouncyCastleProvider();
            Security.addProvider(providerBC);

            InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream("/Users/abhinav/Work/dev/client-wca.p12");

            /* Reading the certificate from a tempory store */
            KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
            ks.load(inStream, "!234Qwer".toCharArray());
            String alias = ks.aliases().nextElement();
            PrivateKey key = (PrivateKey)ks.getKey(alias, "!234Qwer".toCharArray());
            Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate(alias);

            // create PCKS7 for getting attributes
            Certificate[] certificates= Arrays.asList(certificate).toArray(new Certificate[0]);

            //CREATE an empty signature placeholder
            PreSignatureContainerToSign preSignatureContainerToSign = emptySignature("/Users/abhinav/Work/dev/dummy.pdf", "/Users/abhinav/Work/dev/SL_SIGNED.pdf",
                    "sig", certificates, key);

            byte[] signature = sign(preSignatureContainerToSign.hash, key);

            //Sign the PDF with original has
            createSignature("/Users/abhinav/Work/dev/SL_SIGNED.pdf", "/Users/abhinav/Work/dev/SL_SIGNED_f.pdf",
                    "sig", signature, certificates, key, preSignatureContainerToSign);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static byte[] sign(byte[] plainHash, PrivateKey privateKey) throws Exception {
        PrivateKeySignature signature = new PrivateKeySignature(privateKey, "SHA256", "BC");
        return signature.sign(plainHash);
    }

    private PreSignatureContainerToSign emptySignature(String src, String dest, String fieldname, Certificate[] chain, PrivateKey key)
            throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
        PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest), new StampingProperties());
        PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = signer.getSignatureAppearance();
        appearance.setPageRect(new Rectangle(100, 400, 200, 100));
        appearance.setPageNumber(1);
        appearance.setCertificate(chain[0]);
//        appearance.setReason("For test");
//        appearance.setLocation("HKSAR");
        signer.setFieldName(fieldname);

        /*
         * ExternalBlankSignatureContainer constructor will create the PdfDictionary for
         * the signature information and will insert the /Filter and /SubFilter values
         * into this dictionary. It will leave just a blank placeholder for the
         * signature that is to be inserted later.
         */
        PreSignatureContainerToSign external = new PreSignatureContainerToSign(PdfName.Adobe_PPKLite,
                PdfName.Adbe_pkcs7_detached);
        external.setCertificates(chain);
        external.setKey(key);

        // Sign the document using an external container.
        // 8192 is the size of the empty signature placeholder.
        signer.signExternalContainer(external, 8192);
        return external;
    }

    private void createSignature(String src, String dest, String fieldName, byte[] sig, Certificate[] chain,
                                 PrivateKey key, PreSignatureContainerToSign preSignatureContainerToSign)
            throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
        try (FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dest)) {
            PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(reader, os, new StampingProperties());

            PreSignatureContainer external = new PreSignatureContainer(PdfName.Adobe_PPKLite,
                    PdfName.Adbe_pkcs7_detached, true, sig,
                    preSignatureContainerToSign.original, preSignatureContainerToSign.getSgn());
            external.setCertificates(chain);
            external.setKey(key);
            // Signs a PDF where space was already reserved. The field must cover the whole
            // document.
            PdfSigner.signDeferred(signer.getDocument(), fieldName, os, external);
        }
    }

    public class PreSignatureContainer implements IExternalSignatureContainer {
        private PdfDictionary sigDic;
        private PrivateKey key;
        private PdfPKCS7 sgn;
        private Certificate[] certificates;
        private byte hash[];
        private byte[] signature;
        private byte[] original;
        public void setCertificates(Certificate[] certificates) {
            this.certificates = certificates;
        }

        public void setKey(PrivateKey key) {
            this.key = key;
        }

        public PreSignatureContainer(PdfName filter, PdfName subFilter, boolean flag, byte[] signature,  byte[] original,
                                     PdfPKCS7 sgn) {
            sigDic = new PdfDictionary();
            sigDic.put(PdfName.Filter, filter);
            sigDic.put(PdfName.SubFilter, subFilter);
            this.signature = signature;
            this.original = original;
            this.sgn = sgn;
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] sign(InputStream data) throws GeneralSecurityException {
            BouncyCastleDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();

            try {
                var sgn = new PdfPKCS7(null, this.certificates,
                        DigestAlgorithms.SHA256, null, digest, false);
                this.sgn.setExternalDigest(signature,null, "RSA");
                return this.sgn.getEncodedPKCS7(original, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS,
                        null, null, null);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new GeneralSecurityException("PreSignatureContainer signing exception", e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void modifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary signDic) {
            signDic.putAll(sigDic);
        }

        public byte[] getHash() {
            return hash;
        }
    }

    public class PreSignatureContainerToSign implements IExternalSignatureContainer {
        private PdfDictionary sigDic;
        private PrivateKey key;
        private PdfPKCS7 sgn;
        private Certificate[] certificates;
        private byte hash[];
        private byte original[];

        public PdfPKCS7 getSgn() {
            return sgn;
        }

        public void setCertificates(Certificate[] certificates) {
            this.certificates = certificates;
        }

        public void setKey(PrivateKey key) {
            this.key = key;
        }

        public PreSignatureContainerToSign(PdfName filter, PdfName subFilter) {
            sigDic = new PdfDictionary();
            sigDic.put(PdfName.Filter, filter);
            sigDic.put(PdfName.SubFilter, subFilter);
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] sign(InputStream data) throws GeneralSecurityException {
            String hashAlgorithm = "SHA256";
            BouncyCastleDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
            try {
                this.sgn = new PdfPKCS7(null, this.certificates, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256, null,
                        new BouncyCastleDigest(), false);
//                original = DigestAlgorithms.digest(data, digest.getMessageDigest(hashAlgorithm));
                // get attributes
                this.original = sgn.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(DigestAlgorithms.digest(data, digest.getMessageDigest(hashAlgorithm)),
                        PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS,
                        null, null);
                this.hash = DigestAlgorithms.digest(new ByteArrayInputStream(this.original), digest.getMessageDigest(hashAlgorithm));
                return  new byte[0];
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new GeneralSecurityException("PreSignatureContainer signing exception", e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void modifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary pdfDictionary) {
            pdfDictionary.putAll(sigDic);
        }

    }
```

**EDIT**

Fixed the signed attributes and remove the sign simulation using the private key

```
public void testPoints() {
        try{
            BouncyCastleProvider providerBC = new BouncyCastleProvider();
            Security.addProvider(providerBC);

            InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream("/Users/abhinav/Work/dev/client-wca.p12");

            /* Reading the certificate from a tempory store */
            KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
            ks.load(inStream, "!234Qwer".toCharArray());
            String alias = ks.aliases().nextElement();
            PrivateKey key = (PrivateKey)ks.getKey(alias, "!234Qwer".toCharArray());
            Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate(alias);

            // create PCKS7 for getting attributes
            Certificate[] certificates= Arrays.asList(certificate).toArray(new Certificate[0]);

            //CREATE an empty signature placeholder
            PreSignatureContainerToSign preSignatureContainerToSign = emptySignature("/Users/abhinav/Work/dev/dummy.pdf", "/Users/abhinav/Work/dev/SL_SIGNED.pdf",
                    "sig", certificates, key);

//            byte[] signature = sign(preSignatureContainerToSign.hash, key);

            //Sign the PDF with original has
            createSignature("/Users/abhinav/Work/dev/SL_SIGNED.pdf", "/Users/abhinav/Work/dev/SL_SIGNED_f.pdf",
                    "sig", preSignatureContainerToSign.hash, certificates, preSignatureContainerToSign);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static byte[] sign(byte[] plainHash, PrivateKey privateKey) throws Exception {
        PrivateKeySignature signature = new PrivateKeySignature(privateKey, "SHA256", "BC");
        return signature.sign(plainHash);
    }

    private PreSignatureContainerToSign emptySignature(String src, String dest, String fieldname, Certificate[] chain, PrivateKey key)
            throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
        PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest), new StampingProperties());
        PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = signer.getSignatureAppearance();
        appearance.setPageRect(new Rectangle(100, 400, 200, 100));
        appearance.setPageNumber(1);
        appearance.setCertificate(chain[0]);
        signer.setFieldName(fieldname);

        /*
         * ExternalBlankSignatureContainer constructor will create the PdfDictionary for
         * the signature information and will insert the /Filter and /SubFilter values
         * into this dictionary. It will leave just a blank placeholder for the
         * signature that is to be inserted later.
         */
        PreSignatureContainerToSign external = new PreSignatureContainerToSign(PdfName.Adobe_PPKLite,
                PdfName.Adbe_pkcs7_detached);
        external.setCertificates(chain);

        // Sign the document using an external container.
        // 8192 is the size of the empty signature placeholder.
        signer.signExternalContainer(external, 8192);
        return external;
    }

    private void createSignature(String src, String dest, String fieldName, byte[] sig, Certificate[] chain,
                                 PreSignatureContainerToSign preSignatureContainerToSign)
            throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
        try (FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dest)) {
            PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(reader, os, new StampingProperties());

            PreSignatureContainer external = new PreSignatureContainer(PdfName.Adobe_PPKLite,
                    PdfName.Adbe_pkcs7_detached, sig,
                    preSignatureContainerToSign.hash);
            external.setCertificates(chain);
            // Signs a PDF where space was already reserved. The field must cover the whole
            // document.
            PdfSigner.signDeferred(signer.getDocument(), fieldName, os, external);
        }
    }

    public class PreSignatureContainer implements IExternalSignatureContainer {
        private PdfDictionary sigDic;
        private Certificate[] certificates;
        private byte[] signature;
        private byte[] original;
        public void setCertificates(Certificate[] certificates) {
            this.certificates = certificates;
        }

        public PreSignatureContainer(PdfName filter, PdfName subFilter, byte[] signature,  byte[] original) {
            sigDic = new PdfDictionary();
            sigDic.put(PdfName.Filter, filter);
            sigDic.put(PdfName.SubFilter, subFilter);
            this.signature = signature;
            this.original = original;
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] sign(InputStream data) throws GeneralSecurityException {
            BouncyCastleDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
            String hashAlgorithm = "SHA256";
            try {
                byte [] dataDigest = DigestAlgorithms.digest(data, digest.getMessageDigest(hashAlgorithm));
                var sgn = new PdfPKCS7(null, this.certificates,
                        DigestAlgorithms.SHA256, null, digest, false);
                sgn.setExternalDigest(signature,null, "RSA");
                return sgn.getEncodedPKCS7(dataDigest, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS,
                        null, null, null);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new GeneralSecurityException("PreSignatureContainer signing exception", e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void modifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary signDic) {
            signDic.putAll(sigDic);
        }
    }

    public class PreSignatureContainerToSign implements IExternalSignatureContainer {
        private PdfDictionary sigDic;
        private PdfPKCS7 sgn;
        private Certificate[] certificates;
        private byte hash[];
        private byte original[];

        public PdfPKCS7 getSgn() {
            return sgn;
        }

        public void setCertificates(Certificate[] certificates) {
            this.certificates = certificates;
        }

        public PreSignatureContainerToSign(PdfName filter, PdfName subFilter) {
            sigDic = new PdfDictionary();
            sigDic.put(PdfName.Filter, filter);
            sigDic.put(PdfName.SubFilter, subFilter);
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] sign(InputStream data) throws GeneralSecurityException {
            String hashAlgorithm = "SHA256";
            BouncyCastleDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
            try {
                this.sgn = new PdfPKCS7(null, this.certificates, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256, null,
                        new BouncyCastleDigest(), false);

                this.original = DigestAlgorithms.digest(data, digest.getMessageDigest(hashAlgorithm));
                // get attributes
                byte [] docBytes = sgn.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(this.original, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS,
                        null, null);
                this.hash = DigestAlgorithms.digest(new ByteArrayInputStream(docBytes), digest.getMessageDigest(hashAlgorithm));
                return  new byte[0];
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new GeneralSecurityException("PreSignatureContainer signing exception", e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void modifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary pdfDictionary) {
            pdfDictionary.putAll(sigDic);
        }

    }
```

Comment: You nowhere sign the calculated hash, do you? When you call `createSignature` in `testPoints`, you set the `byte[] sig` argument to `preSignatureContainerToSign.hash`, i.e. the unsigned hash.

Comment: As an aside, if you don't have a specific reason for using this two-step approach with deferred signing, you should simplify using a single-step `IExternalSignature` or `IExternalSignatureContainer` use.

Comment: i sign the calculated has using the sign(preSignatureContainerToSign.hash, key) method, and then use this signed hash as an input for setExternalHash. 
I was trying something hence I passed the preSignatureContainerToSign.hash as a parameter 

Reason for two step approach is I have to extend this solution to sign using the DSC residing inside the USB device. If there is a better approach i am open to it since I am pretty new to this.

Comment: *"i sign the calculated has using ..."* - Well, I can only analyze the code you post (where the code path you mention is inactivated by comments). If it differs from what you currently use, how could we help? *"If there is a better approach ..."* - Unless you have to process the signing requests non-synchronously, a single-step approach would be clearly better. But you probably should first resolve the issue at hand. Can you share a PDF signed by your code for analysis? That may help considerably.

Comment: @mkl my bad as I was in the middle of changes, sorry about the changes. I have updated the code and sharing a link to file generated with the same 

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/qzs7jm41cvoa11cx2kz87/SL_SIGNED_f.pdf?rlkey=qqdecbrtjrz47bu14351uqii1&dl=0

Comment: Ok, analyzing your example file I see that the value of the message digest signed attribute is not a hash value but instead is the set of the signed attributes as it should have been. Ok, so your code seems to put the signed attributes generated in the first pass to a wrong use. Ah, ok, following your code that is clear, in `PreSignatureContainerToSign.original` you store the signed attributes and forward them to the `PreSignatureContainer.original` variable. And then you use that value as first parameter of `PdfPKCS7. getEncodedPKCS7`. But in that parameter should be the data stream digest!

Comment: Furthermore, while calculating the signature you hash the data to sign (the attributes) _twice_ in sequence, first explicitly in `PreSignatureContainerToSign.sign` and once implicitly in your static method `sign` (because `PrivateKeySignature` hashes as part of signing). This may change, though, when you switch to signing using the USB device; depending on the API you use to call it, there might not be that implicit signing. Currently, though, this introduces a second error in your signing routine.

Comment: @mkl thanks for your inputs. 

I tried using the data stream digest of the intermediate file in the PreSignatureContainer.sign method, but still I did not get the expected output. (tried with the data stream digest of original file (dummy.pdf) from PreSignatureContainerToSign.sign which failed as well), still getting the document has been modified issue, 

We are testing the USD signing which will happen in two parts, hashed data to be sent to usb and in response will get the signed hash. For now I tried removing the signing simulation as well (sign() method) as well

Comment: Please also again share a PDF created by your current code. Analyzing it tells me where to look in your code for the issue.

Comment: @mkl https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/bxevgkvkvf1prvmojxxb3/SL_SIGNED_f_24032024.pdf?rlkey=bctcbvtxpj7r44r4kjrk69w4x&dl=0

Comment: *"still getting the document has been modified issue, [...] For now I tried removing the signing simulation as well (sign() method) as well"* - Well, indeed, you don't sign the hash. So what you insert as signature bytes, cannot be validated by a signature verifier Thus, the resulting signature container does not represent a valid signature. And that is what Acrobat tells me. It does in particular _not_ say _" the document has been modified"_.

Comment: Thanks @mkl, finally got it to work. Apart from changing the PdfPKCS7. getEncodedPKCS7 first parameter to original data stream digest , i Had to modify the sign() method a bit to sign the hash and voila it worked.

Comment: Great . If you describe the result in an answer, your solution can help others, too.